# What are the C# documentation tags?

Tags: c#, xml, documentation

In C# documentation tags allow you to produce output similar to MSDN.  What are a list of allowable tags for use inside the /// (triple slash) comment area above classes, methods, and properties?

Comment: Look at the documentation from microsoft: [https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/documentation-comments#an-example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Great documentation on the various C# XML documentation tags.](http://web.archive.org/web/20100118163744/http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html) (Go to the bottom to see the tags)

Comment: Alas, the domain has expired and this is a broken link.

Comment: Well that stinks - Google cache still has it, but for how long, who knows?

Comment: I assume this is just like JavaDocs when you publish that to a webpage. More updated link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

Answer (score 15):

If you type this just above a method or class, intellisense should prompt you with a list of available tags:

```
/// <
```

Comment: What do all of them mean in general ? Which order should you use to specify them ? What would be the appropriate use cases for each ? What is possible, but discouraged in modern development practice ?

Answer (score 14):

Here's a list:

- summary
- param
- returns
- example
- code
- see
- seealso
- list
- value
- file
- copyright

Here's an example:

```
<file>
<copyright>(c) Extreme Designers Inc. 2008.</copyright>
<datecreated>2008-09-15</datecreated>
<summary>
Here's my summary
</summary>
<remarks>
<para>The <see cref="TextReader"/> can be used in the following ways:</para>
<list type="number">
<item>first item</item>
<item>second item</item>
</list>
</remarks>
<example>
<code>
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World");
</code>
</example>
<param name="aParam">My first param</param>
<returns>an object that represents a summary</returns>
</file>
```

Comment: There is no author tag for the c#

Comment: What if I have a url I need to point to for more info? Where do I put that?

Comment: @KevinDriedger - I suggest you edit the list and remove the `author` tag. For a moment there I was glad to see it there and then I was disappointed after reading Nap's voted comment and checking it myself with [the link supplied](http://web.archive.org/web/20100118163744/http://thoughtpad.net/alan-dean/cs-xml-documentation.html) [by David Mohundro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989/978502)

Comment: The answer reflects your request @yair

Comment: @KevinDriedger yes, thank you! Now it's more accurate. I don't want to push it (and I'd edit your answer myself if it weren't too big an intervention), but if it had contained [a link to the MSDN recommended doc tags page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments) and also mention here all of the tags that are there (like `permissions` that's missing here and unlike `copyright` that doesn't exist there) - that would be huge improve IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN article from 2002 detailing all the tags and when to use them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) helps by creating a stub comment for your method/class.

Answer (score 2):

See the excellent MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx) as your first stop.

Comment: Link no longer functional. FYI.

Comment: So is just about every link on every answer on this closed question from over a decade ago.

Answer (score 1):

Look inside the docs for [Sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/). This is the new documentation standard for .NET.