# How do I provide custom Intellisense descriptions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Ok so let's say I have the following class in C#:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Bar() { Console.WriteLine("FooBar"); }
}
```

In Visual Studio, whenever I instantiate my class and implement my method intellisense looks like this:

[image: FooBar]

All this is showing is the name, return type and input parameters of my method. When viewing any method inside any of the .Net base classes using intellisense, a description is provided.

How do I add a description for my own methods to intellisense, so anybody who uses a *.dll I have written in the future can understand what my methods do without having to refer to external documentation?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the C# documentation tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969/what-are-the-c-sharp-documentation-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add xml documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Foos something
/// </summary>
public void Foo()
{
}
```